# What does "court" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

> Details about William
>   Shakespeare's life are
>   sketchy, mostly mere
>   surmise based upon court
>   or other clerical records

I'm confused as to whether the intended meaning is a court of law, or the people surrounding Shakespeare, but then again why would a court of law be related to someone's life?

Comment: Basic definition questions are not accepted here. You should use a dictionary to define words. If you have used a dictionary and are unsure which version of the meaning is intended, please include which definitions you think fit and explain your confusion.

Comment: Back in the way back, there weren't many records... when people are trying to figure out whether a person actually existed, **any** records that can be found that are "official" (such as court of law records) are more trustworthy than personal accounts.

Comment: court records means from a court of law. He testified in court and there was a will. Wills are filed in courts.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare's_will#External_links

Answer (score 3):

They likely mean official governmental court (of law) records in this case.

There's always been an air of mystery around the person referred to as "Shakespeare" - some people think that he wasn't a single person at all, or that the person who bore his name didn't actually write the works attributed to it.

When trying to prove that such a person existed, these official records are more trustworthy than personal accounts of friends or acquaintances, which could easily have been false accounts to add to the mythos of this entity.

Comment: There are also records of the royal courts of Elizabeth and James which mention Shakespeare and his company. -- "Some people", by the way, should be "some cranks": no knowledgeable historian of English literature or drama has anything but scorn for the unscholarly anti-Stratfordians.